# how to get my parameters using yargs

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I start my koa app with yarn:

`yarn start --some=123`

The content of `package.json` is:

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=develop nodemon --watch src --exec npm run start:babel -L",
```

My file structure：

```
package.json
src
  -- main.js
  -- config.js
  -- (some other files...)
```

My `config.js` file:

```
import { argv } from 'yargs';
console.log(argv);
```

Will print:

`{ _: [], help: false, version: false, '$0': 'src/main' }`

How can I get the parameters I want? should I change the script in `package.json` file?